How to synchronize nodeID between Master Control and RFID-assisted line-guided AGV in VDA 5050?
I'm working on a project involving a line-guided AGV that uses RFID for additional positioning information. According to the VDA 5050 standard, how can Master Control and the AGV ensure that they both have consistent information about which nodeID corresponds to which physical location?
Any guidance or best practices on this topic would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
